# How to remove substring after a specific character in a list of strings in Python

Tags: python, numpy, replace, split

I have a list of string labels. i want to keep the substring of very element before the second  "." and remove all characters after the second ".".
I found post that show how to do this with a text string using the split function. However, the list datatype does not have a split function. The actual data type is a pandas.core.indexes.base.index which appears to be a list to me.
For the first element in the list,  I want to keep `L1.Energy` and remove everything after the second ".".

```
current_list = ['L1.Energy.Energy', 'L1.Utility.Energy', 'L1.Technology.Utility', 'L1.Financial.Utility']
desired_list = [L1.Energy', 'L1.Utility', 'L1.Technology,'L1.Financial']
```

Comment: Got to be fair, I think Błotosmętek has the best solution ;) but basically all of them work

Comment: What is the issue, though? _I found post that show how to do this with a text string using the split function. However, the list datatype does not have a split function._ That makes little sense, why would you want to use the split technique on the list, instead of the elements themselves?  _The actual data type is a pandas.core.indexes.base.index which appears to be a list to me._ It can't be both, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here as a oneliner:

```
desired_list = [ s[:s.find(".",s.find(".")+1)] for s in current_list]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
current_list = ['L1.Energy.Energy', 'L1.Utility.Energy', 'L1.Technology.Utility', 'L1.Financial.Utility']

desired_list = [ '.'.join(x.split('.')[:2]) for x in current_list ]
```

BTW, this will work also if your labels have more than two dots (like `'L1.Utility.Energy.Electric'`)

Answer (score 0):

Here, its ugly but it works

```
bob = ['L1.Energy.Energy', 'L1.Utility.Energy', 
'L1.Technology.Utility','L1.Financial.Utility']
result = []

for i in bob:
    temp = i.split(".")
    result.append(temp[0] + "." + temp[1])
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `regex`:

```
desired_list = [re.sub('(\..*)(\..*)',r'\1', s) for s in current_list]
```

Output:

```
['L1.Energy', 'L1.Utility', 'L1.Technology', 'L1.Financial']
```